# CFloop through images in a local directory and display in HTML

Tags: html, coldfusion

I'm very new to ColdFusion, I am trying to pull image files from my PC's network directory and display them in an HTML table. This is what I have so far -

```
<cfdirectory action="list" directory="#ExpandPath('file://///network/path/Share-Install/path')#" name="listRoot">

        <cfoutput>

            <cfloop query="listRoot">
                // Build HTML table here maybe?
            </cfloop>

        </cfoutput>
```

If this code is correct its not clear to me how to work with the data brought back from the file/loop. Like I said I'm just now beginning with ColdFusion, so I appreciate any advise with this!

Comment: It's a good start.  You can reduce the amount of code by using `<cfoutput uery="listRoot">`.  It behaves like a loop so you don't need the `<cfloop>` tag.  Also, you don't build the entire html table inside your loop.  The closing and ending `<table>` tags would be outside the loop.  Inside would be `<tr>` tags.

Comment: Thanks! So just kind of guessing, would I be able to work with the data like this? - ```<cfloop query="listRoot">
                <tr><img src="#name#" border="0" alt="" align="absmiddle" /></tr>
            </cfloop>```

Comment: `cfdirectory` returns a query object just like `cfquery` does. Just build the HTML the way you need it to be using the content of the query content. You can `<cfdump var="#listRoot#">` to see what's been returned from the directory read.

Comment: You are forgetting the `<td>` tags.  Also, this is one of those situations where simply trying something is the best way to see if it will work.  You are not going to break anything by displaying images.

Comment: Thank you! Very helpful

Comment: One more thing if anyone has input, with this code - ```<cfdirectory action="list" directory="c:\Share-Install\55555" name="listRoot">
        
    <table>
        <cfoutput query="listRoot">
        <cfdump var="#name#">
            <tr>
                <td colspan="8">Should be loading images right here<img src="#name#" border="0" alt="" align="absmiddle" /></td>
            </tr>
        </cfoutput>
    </table>``` I'm getting the IMG_0878.JPG to print out with the `<cfdump var="#name#">` but for some reason the image isn't being rendered. There's only one image in that path

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using the wrong approach and ended up getting the result I wanted by using `<cfimage>`.
Here is my code that loops through my directory and displays the images in HTML table -

```
<cfdirectory action="list" directory="C:\Share-Install\55555" name="listRoot" filter="*.jpg">

        <table width="100%">
            <tr>
            <cfloop query="listRoot">
                <tr>
                    <td ><cfimage action="writetobrowser" source="/Share-Install/55555/#name#" width="300"></td>
                </tr>
            </cfloop>
        </tr>
        </table>
```

Comment: It may work, but I don't think you actually need cfimage. A plain image tag, with the correct path, should do the same `<img src="/Share-Install/55555/#name#">`.  Though you'd need to use a <cfoutput> (not cfloop) to ensure the #name# variable is evaluated.